# How to take thumbnail image from video bytes[] using java?

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, fancybox, javacv

My requirement is, i want to show video thumbnail in fancybox. But unfortunatly its not showing thumbnail. its required seperate image for thumbnail.

Sample fancybox code

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-width="640" data-height="360" href="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/bird1.jpg" />
</a>
```

So i decided to maintain two url

one for video and other for video thumbnail.

1. http://localhost:8080/resources?resourceId=126 -> it will return video
2. http://localhost:8080/resources?resourceId=126&thumbnail=true -> it will return thumbnail image

I haven't any idea about this but I had tried for video thumbnail with https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv. But i got '**OutofMemory**' exception

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

My java servlet code for thumbnail image is as follows

```
Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
BufferedImage current;
BufferedImage next;
byte[] videoBytes = //video byte array fetched from db
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(new ByteArrayInputStream(videoBytes));
frameGrabber.start();
try {
    Frame frame = frameGrabber.grab();
    next = converter.convert(frame);

    current = new BufferedImage(next.getWidth(), next.getHeight(), next.getType());
    ImageIO.write(current, "png", baos);
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    frameGrabber.stop();


    response.setContentType("image/png");
    try (OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream()) {
        o.write(bytes);
        o.flush();
    }
```

### Edit

Video section is working fine. i.e. can able to view video from this url http://localhost:8080/resources?resourceId=126

Comment: Can you share the full traceback of OOM error ? Also which device are you trying to run this script ?

Comment: 14:16:58,671 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-112) UT005023: Exception handling request to /resources: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes (944M) > maxPhysicalBytes (911M)
 at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:700)
 at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:126)
 at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.Cb_PointerPointer_int.allocate(Native Method)
 at org.bytedeco.ffmpeg.avcodec.Cb_PointerPointer_int.<init>(Cb_PointerPointer_int.java:49)
 at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegLockCallback$1.<init>(FFmpegLockCallback.java:20)

Comment: Windows 10 + java8 + JBoss7.1